# Hello world kconfig and makefile to make it similar to linux kernel menuconfig

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu, kbuild

How can I implement hello world Makefile & Kconfig?

I know how to write Makefile, but how can we write Makefile and Kconfig similar to Linux Kernel.
I want to write small program for which I can open menuconfig similar to Linux Kernel?

I don't want it for Linux Kernel module compilation, I know that part, I want to learn to make any application to convert into such a configurable app.

Any sample pointers where should I start from?

Comment: `where should I start from?` - Start from the kernel's Makefile code. `make menuconfig` actually calls some program, which is built using `ncurses` library.

Comment: Following might help         http://www.denx.de/wiki/pub/U-Boot/MiniSummitELCE2014/uboot2014_kconfig.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question properly then you must be asking about in tree build of your loadable module with kernels build process.
Kconfig is responsible for the respective value/loadable module to be visible in menuconfig(I use menuconfig for kernel configuration).

To keep things simple let's follow below:
Create dir on ~/drivers directory nammed mymod.
In ~/drivers/mymod create Kconfig and Makefile files and keep your helloKernelmod.c

In Kconfig keep below content

```
menu "Menu Name of Your Driver"

config HELLO_MODULE 
      tristate "Inside Menu Name"
      help
          This is help/informational content for your module
endmenu
```

In makefile keep below content

```
obj-$(CONFIG_HELLO_MODULE)     +=helloKernelmod.o
```

these updates will do the trick and your module will be built.
Add tabs for indentation
For more information go to https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/kconfig-language.txt